# MySql Workbench Can't connect to database directly

Tags: mysql

I have this right configuration for my database connection.

Currently my configuration works only if I don't specify a `Default Schema`

but when I put the database name, it prompts a dialog saying

```
Please enter password for the following service:
Service:Mysql@127.0.0.1:3306...some long text
User:xbin_sql
Password:
```

but when I type my password it promts an error

```
Failed to connect ....
Access Denied....
```

I don't know why but my password and username is correct

[image]

Comment: You may need to configure your SSH settings in MySQL requires that.

Comment: If you leave the `Default Schema:` empty and the connection works, but when you enter a value, the connection doesn't work... that sounds like either the database ("Schema") doesn't exist, or your user doesn't have privileges on it. As root (or other sufficiently privilege MySQL user, `CREATE DATABASE xbin_db`, or `GRANT ALL ON xbin_db.* TO 'xbin_sql'@'127.0.0.1'` (or `'xbin_sql'@'%'`), depending on which user is defined and you're connecting as.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I see.. I'll try granting the current user. but. why does it allow to connect if no schema was specified?

Comment: @Snippet: the user can connect because the user is defined; connecting to the MySQL server is a privilege that's separate from object level privileges in a database. (The `GRANT ALL` was just an example, if you only need SELECT and DML privileges in the database, `GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON xbin_db.* TO ...`. (As to why the connect is failing, MySQL may be throwing an error, and the client is aborting the connection. But we'd expect the client to give us an indication of that, like showing the actual MySQL error.